# Pyspark. Getting only minimal values

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I want to get only minimum values.

```py
import pyspark as ps

spark = ps.sql.SparkSession.builder.master('local[4]')\
    .appName('some-name-here').getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext

sc.textFile('path-to.csv')\
    .map(lambda x: x.replace('"', '').split(','))\
    .filter(lambda x: not x[0].startswith('player_id'))\
    .map(lambda x: (x[2] + " " + x[1], int(x[8]) if x[8] else 0))\
    .reduceByKey(lambda value1, value2: value1 + value2)\
    .sortBy(lambda price: price[1], ascending=True).collect()
```

This is what I get:

`[('Cedric Ceballos', 0), ('Maurcie Cheeks', 0), ('James Foster', 0), ('Billy Gabor', 0), ('Julius Keye', 0), ('Anthony Mason', 0), ('Chuck Noble', 0), ('Theo Ratliff', 0), ('Austin Carr', 0), ('Mark Eaton', 0), ('A.C. Green', 0), ('Darrall Imhoff', 0), ('John Johnson', 0), ('Neil Johnson', 0), ('Jim King', 0), ('Max Zaslofsky', 1), ('Don Barksdale', 1), ('Curtis Rowe', 1), ('Caron Butler', 2), ('Chris Gatling', 2)].`

As you can see there are a lot of keys with value 0, which is the minimum value. How can I sort it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can collect the minimum value into a variable, and do an equality filter based on that variable:

```
rdd = sc.textFile('path-to.csv')\
    .map(lambda x: x.replace('"', '').split(','))\
    .filter(lambda x: not x[0].startswith('player_id'))\
    .map(lambda x: (x[2] + " " + x[1], int(x[8]) if x[8] else 0))\
    .reduceByKey(lambda value1, value2: value1 + value2)\
    .sortBy(lambda price: price[1], ascending=True)

minval = rdd.take(1)[0][1]
rdd2 = rdd.filter(lambda x: x[1] == minval)
```

Comment: Since take() returns to the driver, would it make sense to broadcast `minval` before the filter?

Answer (score 0):

Your data is already sorted. Use `take(1)` rather than `collect()` to get the first element, the minimum